# Visual Studio 2012 Crashes on opening designer for 1 specific windows form

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-forms-designer

I'm currently working on a project. This project is shared by teamfoundation between colleagues.
I need to change some things in a windows form. But when i open the windows form in the designer, Visual Studio 2012 crashes and does a restart. It gives no errors, ontly that Visual Studio has stopped working. This problem only exist with this specific windows form.

With the same build on a computer of a colleague, it can be opened. My OS is windows 8(64bit) and the OS of the colleague is windows 7 (64bit).

Does this sound familiar to anyone, or is there a way to find errorlogs so i can see some more information?

Thank you in advance!

If you need more information, please let me know!

Comment: It is not unusual, event handlers in the form can run at design-time as well and cause exceptions.  There's one that is particularly nasty and will cause VS to terminate.  They named this site for it.  Debug it starting another instance of VS and using Tools + Attach to Process to attach to the first.

Comment: Thanks, now i get an error in 2nd visual studio. From code from the project. System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Strange... im gonna do some more research.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue with both VS2010 and VS2012.  I found that if I do any form designer work in a VS instance, it is corrupting the designer file when it rewrites it.  Currently, my work-around is to do the form designer work using VS2005 then compiling using VS2012.  This is not my permanent solution but it's all I have so far.  Good luck!